# bind click after unbind the click

Tags: jquery

I wanted to bind the click event after unbinding the click event. For eg. If you click on button one then this unbind this button and when you click in button two then it should bind the click event of button one again. But binding click event seems not working.

```
$('#one').on('click',function(){  <<----------------------  
    alert('one clicked');                                | 
    $(this).off('click');                             click
});                                                      |
$('#two').on('click',function(){                      event
    alert('two clicked');                                |
    $('#one').on('click'); >>---------not binding the-----
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DGW8y/)

---

Ps: without using flagged variable.

Comment: Note that in the API that `handler` is a required parameter for `.on()`: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a `click` handler instead of binding with `anonymous` function. Binding click method using `on` need to provide the the *event handler* which you did not provide in #two click handler.

If you look at the documentation of on, [.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler(eventObject) )](http://api.jquery.com/on/) you will see the **handler is not optional** here.

You can pass false in place of handler but that means you have a function that simply returns false.

> A function to execute when the event is triggered. The value false is
>   also allowed as a shorthand for a function that simply does return
>   false, [jQuery api](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handlereventObject).

```
$('#two').on('click',oneclickhandler);

$('#two').on('click',function(){
    alert('two clicked');
    $('#one').on('click', oneclickhandler);
});

function oneclickhandler(){
    alert('one clicked');
    $(this).off('click');
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought it was optional.

Answer (score 0):

Use a named handler and use .one() to register the handler

```
function handler() {
    alert('one clicked');
}
$('#one').one('click', handler);
$('#two').on('click', function () {
    alert('two clicked');
    $('#one').on('click', handler);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2tgZP/)

Answer (score 0):

I just tried and its work great now.You can use `bind`

```
$('#one').on('click',clickevent);

function clickevent(){    
    alert('one clicked');                                
    $(this).off('click');                  
}                                                     
$('#two').on('click',function(){                      
    alert('two clicked');                                
    $('#one').bind('click',clickevent); 
});
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/96MD3/1/)